# Indexes execution flow in select statements

Tags: sql, oracle

My question is about the flow execution how will be, if select statement has where clause that depends on two value, one of them is from indexed column and the other is not. 
Example:

```
Select * from table1 where col1 = 'val1' and col2 = 'val2';
```

if we supposed col1 is indexed and col2 is not. And if col2 indexed and col1 does not, does it differ?

**Updated**

What I want to ask about is, does the query getting faster if there is one column with index and the other with not ? Is it the same if where clause depends only on one indexed column?

Comment: It also depends on cardinality (the number of rows with `val1` in `col1`, if `col1` is the one indexed). Best thing to do is run the query and see what the execution plan says. Otherwise, this is too broad and open to speculation.

Comment: Yes it differ. What problem are you trying to solve? Answer to your question is broad.

Comment: What I want to ask about is, does the query getting faster if there is one column with index and the other with not ? Is it the same if where clause depends only on one indexed column?

Comment: You should look at the query plan. If for example your index is not selective it will probably never be used no matter what you do. It's possible it might use the index first and after that filter the 'residual' on the non indexed column. But if it's quicker to do a table scan (i.e. your index is not selective enough) it won't use the index.

Comment: what did you mean about "your index is not selective enough" ?

Comment: Check the execution plan.

Answer (score -2):

According to 70-461 materials:

```
FROM ON JOIN WHERE GROUP BY WITH CUBE or WITH ROLLUP HAVING SELECT
DISTINCT ORDER BY TOP
```

E.g. If you have `SELECT C1 AS x`
You can't put `WHERE x IS NOT NULL`

The sequence of predicates in WHERE claus is defined by sql server based on parameters that only Microsoft knows.